# VBA for Excel; Can Hyperlinks.Add target more than one cell in another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

My Code part:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 12), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "Sheet2" & "'!" & Cells(1,1).Address
```

But i dont like to link only to `Cells(1,1)`. I would like to link `Cells(1,1)` To `Cells(5,1)` so that they are selected every time i click the hyperlink.
Is this possible?

Thank you
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding hyperlinks with a range as an adress use something like this

```
Sub stacktest()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wsB As Worksheet

Set wsA = Worksheets(1)
Set wsB = Worksheets(2)

wsA.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 12), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "Sheete2" & "'!" & wsB.Range(wsB.Cells(1, 1), wsB.Cells(1, 5)).Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When hyperlink is clicked it goes to below function. Based on hyperlink cell value insert code in below case. that way you can make hyperlink to do more than one task for you

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, _
    ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    intColNum = Int(ActiveCell.Column)
    intRowNum = Int(ActiveCell.Row)

 Select Case UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(intRowNum, intColNum).Value)

 Case "RUN TEST"
  'TestRun
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `External` parameter of the `Range.Address` to equal True.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim i

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For i = 2 To 10

            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 12), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 11)).Address(External:=True)

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```